# jQuery cookie to remember which nav list is open?

Tags: jquery, menu, jquery-cookie

I have cobbled the below together in my (very) humble jQuery hackish way:

```
$(".toggle_container").hide();
                $(".trigger a").addClass("close");
                $(".trigger a").click(function() {
                $(".toggle_container").slideUp('200','swing');
                 $(".trigger a").removeClass("open").addClass("close");
                    if     ($(this).next(".toggle_container").is(":hidden")) {
                            $(this).next(".toggle_container").stop(true,false).slideToggle('200','swing');

                        }
                });
```

jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FWzWu/8/

I have never used the jquery cookie plugin, but would like to use it now to remember the users menu state from page to page. Using the github plugin here: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Any help is most appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Honestly I don't know what the set the cookie as and how to combine it with what I have so far.

Comment: Or what to do to read it back and set the nav for that matter.

Comment: Aren't [sessions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) in PHP a better option for this? If you have jquery doing things without page reloads then you can use AJAX to update the session variables. You will lose the menu state when the user navigates away from the page though but if you are using it only from page to page then I'd use sessions.

Comment: I'm in SASS hosted environment on this one. No seversides. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[A first stab](http://jsfiddle.net/forloop/TekUY/)** (I added a call to `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default anchor action from happening on click - you may need to remove this).

It could do with some cleaning up, for example it would be good to take advantage of event delegation to capture the click event on anchor elements, hopefully it conveys how to use the plugin and where to use it.

```
 $(function () {   

    // give each container a unique class
    var containers = $("ul.toggle_container").hide().each(function (i,v) {
        $(this).addClass('container_' + i);       
    });

    var value = $.cookie('toggled_container');     

    // if we have a value in the cookie, use it to show that container
    if (value) {
        $('ul.' + value).show();
    }

    var anchors = $("li.trigger a");

    anchors.addClass("close").click(function() {
        containers.slideUp('200','swing');
        anchors.removeClass("open").addClass("close");
        var nextContainer = $(this).next("ul.toggle_container");
        if (nextContainer.is(":hidden")) {
            // capture the unique class that we have given the container
            $.cookie('toggled_container', nextContainer.attr('class').match(/container_\d+/));
            nextContainer.stop(true,false).slideToggle('200','swing');
        }
    });
});
```

Obviously, this solution assumes that your containers are never going to change in number and order; if they do, the wrong container will end up being expanded on page load :)

Comment: Thank you Russ! Could the same method be done with a universal "hidden" class with display none or similar? Or because of the setting of the cookie we have to have uniques?

Comment: @Jamie we ideally want a unique identifier for the open container as this will be the quickest (and easiest) way to find the correct container when the DOM is ready, and to store a value in the cookie when the container is open. Now we could get it by ordinal position in the DOM, but we don't really want to calculate this each time we're storing a value, so we're effectively calculating unique identifiers once on DOM ready and using those whilst the page remains loaded. If it were me, I'd probably have ids on the containers in the markup sent from the server

Comment: Thank you for your help Russ. I really appreciate you taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

On the page you list (the github one) there is a [readme](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.rdoc), I've never used the plugin but it looks simple enough.

Make sure you include the script;

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Now every time you want to change the cookies value (or create the cookie in the first place) use;

```
$.cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', { expires: 7 });
```

change *cookie_name* and *cookie_value* to whatever you desire. For example

```
$.cookie('nav_choice', '1', { expires: 7 });
```

Then every time you load the page run this inside the document.ready;

```
var nav = $.cookie('nav_choice');
```

Then you can run if() statements to determine what to display.

Does this help? I can elaborate if necessary.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle and may have screwed it up playing around.